# Getting "Debug: request, closed, error" with Hapi JS

Tags: node.js, debugging, post, runtime-error, hapi.js

I have cloned the Repo & installed all dependencies. When I try to run on localhost for POST/PUT methods, the request is loading and in logs getting `Debug: request, closed, error`. But the other side GET is working properly.
Is any way to resolve this issue?

Comment: Please put the code in your question. We are not able to help with debug if we have no code

Comment: I am seeing the same issue on a hapi 16 app that I have updated to using node 16. Does that situation match yours at all?